# Assert value with assertJ in Optional

Tags: java, option-type, assertj

I have two classes:

```
class Outer {
    Inner inner = new Inner("value");
}

class Inner {
   private final String value;
   
   Inner(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}

public Optional<Outer> getOptionalValue() {
   return Optional.of(new Outer());
}
```

And my test:

```
public void testCLass() {
   Assertions.assertThat(getOptionalValue())
      .isPresent()
      .map(v -> v.inner.value)
      .isEqualTo("value");
}
```

I expect it to pass, because `isPresent` unwraps optional, `map` converts `Outer` into `value` and in the last method I just compare strings.

But it fails on the last line with the message:

```
Expecting:
 <Optional[value]>
to be equal to:
 <"value">
but was not.
```

I have no idea why the optional is not unwrapped

Comment: I think also you have a typo `.map(v -> v.inner.value)` I think you are using getter to access to the value

Comment: @YCF_L this particular example is without getter

Answer (score 50):

The javadoc for [`OptionalAssert`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/OptionalAssert.html)'s [map](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractOptionalAssert.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method states

> Call `map` on the `Optional` under test, assertions chained afterwards are performed on the `Optional` resulting from the `map` call.

However, [`isEqualTo`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#isEqualTo(java.lang.Object)) is actually comparing the value of the `AbstractAssert` as a whole. It's not overriden for `OptionalAssert` to compare the enclosed value. An `OptionalAssert`'s value, the `Optional` itself, is not equal to a `String`.

You'll want to use [`hasValue`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractOptionalAssert.html#hasValue(VALUE))

> Verifies that the actual `Optional` contains the given value (alias of `contains(Object)`).
>
> Assertion will pass :
>
> ```
> assertThat(Optional.of("something")).hasValue("something");
> assertThat(Optional.of(10)).contains(10);
> ```

So

```
Assertions.assertThat(getOptionalValue())
      .isPresent()
      .map(v -> v.inner.value)
      .hasValue("value");
```

Or, because `hasValue` actually performs the `isPresent` check internally, you could just use

```
Assertions.assertThat(getOptionalValue())
      .map(v -> v.inner.value)
      .hasValue("value");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a step, you should to use `get()` to get the value of the Optional, because map in your case, returns an `Optional<String>` and not a String:

```
.map(v -> v.inner.getValue())
.get()
.isEqualTo("value");
```

---

Or if you want to stick with the `Optional`, you should to compare with an `Optional`:

```
.map(v -> v.inner.getValue())
.isEqualTo(Optional.of("value"));
```

Comment: Is there any explanation to this? Why has it wrapped `outer.inner.value` into Optional?

Comment: @a3dsfcv I state it in my answer, [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) return an `Optional`, in your case an Optional of String because `v.inner.getValue()` is a String

Answer (score 1):

If you can, make the test directly on the received `Optional` rather than taking it apart and testing three levels deep.

```
    Assertions.assertThat(getOptionalValue()).hasValue(new Outer());
```

It’s clear and simple, it’s the recommended way, and if `Outer` and `Inner` have appropriate `equals` methods, you need nothing more. While I haven’t tried it with AssertJ myself, I believe that it gives clear messages both in the case where the `Optional` is empty and in the case where it holds an incorrect value at some level.